# Material UI, internal link scrolling not working on mobile

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, next.js

I am using internal links such as `/lessons/lesson-slug#heading-slug` for internal scrolling on a page. All of this works totally fine on desktop, but breaks on mobile view with an overlaid drawer nav component. See screen recording:

[image]

I can't pinpoint where the problem is... I have already tried passing these ModalProps on the Drawer component, but no luck sofar:

```
ModalProps={{
            hideBackdrop: true,
            disableScrollLock: true,
            disablePortal: true,
            disableAutoFocus: true
          }}
```

Any ideas? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Adding `disableEnforceFocus: true` fixed it.